# how to display the scheduled amount in listview with next three month from the current month

Tags: vb.net

e-g if in listview one column name is as scheduled amount this column value should be shown in last three columns with month name 
for example like-
scheduled
 amount  november december january 
          15000   15000    15000     15000

for two months
 amount  november december january 
 
               15000   15000    15000     0

for quaterly
 amount  november december january 
             15000    0        0       15000

like if scheduled type is 1 month it should display the value in next three month like november=15000, december=15000, january=15000 and if it is 2months it should display the value in november and december ans if it is selected as quarterly it should display the value in third month like january=15000. please also lemme know is it possible to show the next three months as header name in listview where the month name will keep changing as per the current date and month. help will be really appreciated.
thanks n regards.

Comment: please show the code you have tried

Comment: @ Plutonix- i havent tried any code yet for this i can show you my previous code which i have done for displaying the values in listview.

Comment: Well, the VB namespace has `MonthName(ByVal Month As Integer, Optional ByVal Abbreviate As Boolean = False) As String` which would get you the month name, so get the next 3 names from there.

Comment: how should i show the month name as column name in listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lv.Columns(0).Text = thisMonthName
lv.Columns(1).Text = nextMonthName
lv.Columns(2).Text = nextnextMonthName
```

or use a loop based on the start and stop month where you fetch the monthname and post to the aptly named and hideously easy to find `Columns` collection in your listview.

Be sure the listview is in details view (before you ask, set `View` to `Details` in the props window)

Comment: @ plutonix thank you so much really appreciated thanks once again :)
* stay blessed *